# Resetting pending updates

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

There are times hen the telegram bot is unresponsive and I need to remove the pending updates. If I use this part &drop_pending_updates=true in the webhook URL then the problem is solved instantly. For e.g.

https://api.telegram.org/botYOURTOKEN/setWebhook?url=https://yoururl.com&drop_pending_updates=true

But I have to do this frequently these days. Is there a solution?